# RxJS Observables: new request depending on previous result

Tags: rxjs, observable

How can I generate new values to an Observable or Subject depending on received values?

*Example:*

*Let's say I have an Observable that emits one random number thanks to a web API.*

*If it is an even number, I want the Observable to emit another random number using the first one as a seed... and so on until I get an odd value.*

Note that I don't know in advance how many requests I'm going to make.

Until now, I managed to do it with "weird", recursive methods, but I feel like there must be a much proper way to do this.

Comment: So if it is even number you want to call web api with that number as a parameter or what does "seed" mean?. If so, what is your initial "seed" value?

Comment: Yes, the previous number should be a parameter to the web API. My point was that I had to use the previous value to modify the request that the Observable is sending and not only repeat the same request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can use `expand()` for this.

```
const source$ = /* some API call that returns an Observable */;

source$.pipe(
  expand((previous: number) => previous % 2 === 0 ? source$ : EMPTY),
  takeLast(1),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

This gives you only the last value (the first odd). If you want to get all the intermediate values as well just remove that `takeLast(1)`.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-czomtm

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. I forked your demo so I could use the previous value as a "seed" : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cyjjzj